# How to sum numbers that are in currency format using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, currency

I am trying to sum up the following numbers.

```
 var number1= 12,000.00 ;  var number2= 12,000.00;
```

I have tried this `alert(number1+number2);​` but it doesn't return any data.

Could you please help me to solve this problem?

Thanks

Comment: This is invalid javascript. You can't have a `,` inside a numeric literal. You have to store it as a string, then parse it manually

Comment: This is not a correct definition. Either you define your variable value as a string or with other delimitator, otherwise you will lead the interpretor into a rap, thinking that the value after the comma is another variable.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The code in your question is invalid javascript. You can't have a `,` inside a numeric literal. You have to store it as a string, then parse it manually:

```
var number1 = '12,000.00';
var number2 = '12,000.00';

function parseCurrency( num ) {
    return parseFloat( num.replace( /,/g, '') );
}

alert( parseCurrency(number1) + parseCurrency(number2) );
```

Comment: @imsky Oh right, currency can have cents... Switched to `parseFloat` :)

Answer (score 3):

This won't work. Use [accounting.js](http://josscrowcroft.github.com/accounting.js/)'s `unformat` function to parse 12,000 as a string instead.

Comment: Thanks a lot imsky, for introducing me with the accounting.js plugin? I think its awesome, though I don't need that plugin now but I think it will help me a lot in the future :)Thanks